# react-native access phone camera

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, react-native

I am building an android app with react-native.
It's a simple messaging app where you can send pictures.

I tried some components like react-native-camera but I'm not completely satisfied with the performance.

I was thinking to do it like Cordova/pg does, accessing the default camera app to take pictures, like Slack does in the android app.

Does someone knows to do that? It's possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker - you can access the camera directly via the default camera app.

Comment: But I want to open the camera for example when I press a button, but I dont want the camera to be inside my app